# Want to show sunrise/sunset time on website

Tags: time

On my website I want to display the sunrise and sunset time of a the place from where the person is opening the webpage. Now Google Web Search give the sunrise and sunset time if you search like this :`http://www.google.com/search?q=sunrise:<city_name>` . How can I use this to provide this functionality on my website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking for a similar service and found http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#sun

Here's an example for New York for the 4th December:

```
http://www.earthtools.org/sun/40.71417/-74.00639/4/12/-5/0
```

Comment: Thank you!! That was a great answer and exactly what I wanted!!

Comment: Their website provides information as to how to calculate these yourself if you were interested: `Sunrise/Sunset Times

The sunrise and sunset times are calculated using a PHP script using formulae from www.srrb.noaa.gov [NOA06]. The times given do not currently automatically take account of daylight saving time (summer time). To take DST into account, make sure the "DST" box is checked.`