# How can I get sun rise and sun set times for various locations?

Tags: android, api, libraries

I am planning to develop an application for which I need to know the sun rise and sun set times of any day (in atleast an year complete) depending upon the place (zone/city).

Considering that I need to develop such an application for Android and also for a desktop application, I would like to know if there are any APIs or libraries for the same that could help me get these data easily.

PS: Though I mentioned both Android and desktop, the preference is more for the former but it would be nice to use an API that is compliant for both.

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://mikereedell.github.com/sunrisesunsetlib-java/), it might be helpful for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564972/i-need-a-sunrise-sunset-webservice-api

Answer (score 3):

Simple Research found the following:

- [Want to show sunrise/sunset time on website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102178/want-to-show-sunrise-sunset-time-on-website)
- https://developers.google.com/search?q=google+weather+api

Option that costs money:

- http://portal.theweatherchannel.com/

**Free Solution: Gets you an RSS feed returning a direct link to an XML file with all the data including sunrise / sunset times**

- http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

PS: You can also compute it directly using algorithms available online, but using an API would probably be best

EDIT: I fixed the bad formatting. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can take for 7 days forecast:

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/auto_weather

Here is the full request:

https://weather.cit.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=forecast_astronomy&name=Chicago&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

You can simply change city's name from Chicago to your cityName

[Here you can see how it looks JSON format of request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDC6M.png)