# Calculate sunrise and sunset in javascript for user's location when they visit site

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I calculate the sunrise and sunset in the area that the user is visiting a site in with javascript / jquery ?

I tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182451/how-to-calculate-the-sunrise-and-sunset-in-javascript), but didn't get much help from the answers.

I just want to be able to print sunrise: sunrise time is here and sunset: sunset time here.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to use XMLHTTPRequest to a script that returns the result from PHP's date_sunrise/date_sunset methods:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-sunrise.php

Otherwise, you'll have to maintain a database of the required information and reproduce that algorithm. However, this looks like it might do it out of the box:

http://www.github.com/mourner/suncalc‎

Comment: Hmmm interesting. How can I get the longitude and latitude of the user's machine then to pass to those functions?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to query an existing service. Here is a similar question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102178/want-to-show-sunrise-sunset-time-on-website)